# Passing run_date in seconds to apscheduler's add_job

Tags: python-3.x, apscheduler

I want to schedule a function in APScheduler to happen only once in the specified time from now. The `run_date` date trigger accepts datetime objects and/or strings there of:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import os

from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler

try:
    import asyncio
except ImportError:
    import trollius as asyncio


def tick():
    print('Tick! The time is: %s' % datetime.now())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(tick, 'date', run_date=datetime.fromordinal(datetime.toordinal(datetime.now())+1))
    scheduler.start()
    print('Press Ctrl+{0} to exit'.format('Break' if os.name == 'nt' else 'C'))

    # Execution will block here until Ctrl+C (Ctrl+Break on Windows) is pressed.
    try:
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        pass
```

Is there a built-in functionality in APScheduler to specify the delay time directly in seconds, e.g.something like `application_start_time + specified_delay`? I tried `datetime.fromordinal(datetime.toordinal(datetime.now())+1)` as argument to `run_date` for 1 second after the starting point of my application, but this only hangs for ever without calling the tick function showing the following deprecation message:

```
Press Ctrl+C to exit
/tmp/a.py:30: DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
  asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

What you probably wanted was:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

scheduler.add_job(tick, "date", run_date=datetime.now(timezone.utc) + timedelta(seconds=1))
```